# Selecting records in Postgres when using ANY and arrays on bytea columns

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jdbc

I am having trouble querying on bytea columns using the '=ANY(?)' condition in my Postgres database.
I define a table with bytea column, inserting a byte[] works ok, but the query does not return any results.

See this snippet:

```
    private static void selectBytes(String url, String username, String password) throws Exception
{
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
    statement.execute("create table bytetest(x bytea)");
    statement.close();

    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into bytetest(x) values(?)");
    ps.setBytes(1, new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
    ps.execute();
    ps.close();

    statement = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select count(*) from bytetest");
    rs.next();
    System.out.println("Number of records: " + rs.getInt(1));
    rs.close();
    statement.close();

    ps = conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) from bytetest where x = ANY(?)");
    Array array = conn.createArrayOf("bytea", new Object[] { new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 } });
    ps.setArray(1, array);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    System.out.println("Number of selected records: " + rs.getInt(1));
    rs.close();
    ps.close();

    ps = conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) from bytetest where x = ?");
    ps.setBytes(1, new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    System.out.println("Number of selected records directly: " + rs.getInt(1));
    rs.close();
    ps.close();

    conn.close();
}
```

The output is :

```
Number of records: 1
Number of selected records: 0
Number of selected records directly: 1
```

Output from the log shows that the array is not interpreted the same way as the single value.

```
LOG:  execute <unnamed>: select count(*) from bytetest where x = ANY($1)
DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '{{"\\x31","\\x32","\\x33","\\x34"}}'
LOG:  execute <unnamed>: select count(*) from bytetest where x = $1
DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '\x01020304'
```

This is with the PostgreSQL 9.6.3 and the postgresql-42.2.10 driver.
How can I select my data with ANY and binary data in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Your query doesn't make much sense to me. Why are you using `= ANY(?)` here, and not just `= ?`?

Comment: I want to query with multiple byte arrays, this is just the most simple example I could come up with.